# Is "green ones" not slang for money?

Tags: american-english, british-english, slang, popular-refrains, international

> I wish I could bring in some green ones.

> I cannot bring in the green ones.

> I'm making tons of the green ones.

Are these proper English/American English sentences? Can you use "green ones" to mean "money"? I've failed to find it looking it up on Wikitionary, Dictionary.com and others.

Is it only "the greens"? Not "the green ones"?

Comment: It doesn't work in British English as British 'paper' currency isn't green.

Comment: In the US, (paper) dollars used to be called ***greenbacks***, but that's probably a bit dated now. See [Making sense of dollars and “geetus”.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/408186/making-sense-of-dollars-and-geetus?rq=1)

Comment: There are a range of expressions around "green" for currency in the US: "green", "greenbacks", references to green things like "cabbage". In context it is usually understandable even if you don't know the exact idiom. Not familiar with "green ones" but I guess it could be comprehended. https://www.wix.com/wordsmatter/blog/2020/09/slang-for-money/ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slang_terms_for_money

Comment: If you’re a colorer, “green ones” are crayons.

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard an American say 'green ones' for money. What Americans do say is 'green.'

> I wish I could bring in some green

That would work. I would not expect it to work in other English speaking countries because their currency isn't all green.

Someone else's question:

[Meaning of "Green" and "GreenBack" in American english?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/263943/meaning-of-green-and-greenback-in-american-english)

Answer (score 0):

*A ton of green ones* is okay because ‘a ton’ is hyperbole. It sets the tone, so the listener is ready to absorb more slang.

Normally the green ones are not in verbal circulation. They ring old movies.

Answer (score 0):

As an American, I haven't heard the term "green ones" used in conversation, nor do I use it. I may have heard it in a song? It does make sense though because all of our physical money is green.

But if I was going to use "the green ones" or "greens ones", instead of the word "money". I would use "green ones" over "the green ones". This is because money is usually an implied plural and "the" is more often used to denote a single object, but this is not always true.

If you were wanting to use an article, ***use "those" or "these" instead of "the"*** since money is an implied plural. "Those" or "these" are the plural forms of "the".

*Ex: "Those green ones keep coming in!"*

Your example sentences will probably sound a little stiff to an American ear. Maybe try these instead...
*Ex: "I can't bring in green ones."* (Americans will usually use the contracted form of any contraction, especially in the south. **DISCLAIMER**: This is only true for informal speech.)
**Uncontracted:** "***I am*** making tons of green ones." **Contracted:** "***I'm*** making tons of those greens ones."

But since "green ones" is slang, I could see it being used more like...
*"Dude, I just can't bring in those green ones."* or
*"All **these** green ones keep coming my way."* or *"All **those** green ones keep coming my way."*

But if you are speaking with Americans, they may associate "green ones" or especially "the green ones" ***with aliens***. In America, a common idea of aliens is usually either grey or green men, commonly known as "little green men".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_green_men

I hope this helps!!

Comment: All true for “green ones”, but “green” (uncountable noun) would be understood. “I need some green”. Though that might instead mean marijuana in certain contexts...